Mercurial push to remote repo blocked by its own locks
My issue is similar to others here, but not exactly.  I cannot push from Linux to a remote repo on a Windows network share that is mounted with CIFS.  I have had no problem for years, then it recently broke.  A recent Ubuntu update seemed to have broken network connectivity but reinstalling Network Manager fixed that.  I'm not sure if it's related.
There are no locks (.hg/lock or .hg/store/wlock) in the remote repo before I push.  When I push I get the message

waiting for lock on working directory of <repo path> held by ''

And the quotes at the end are actually empty.  Now when I look in the remote repo I can see the .hg/wlock lock.  If I delete it, it is immediately recreated.  The push process never unblocks and all I can do is CTRL-C.
I read about debuglocks.  When I issue the command hg debuglocks in the remote repo I get this

lock:   (0s)
wlock:  (0s)

and I can see that Mercurial has actually created those locks during that command.  A minute or so later hg debuglocks yields

lock:   (87s)
wlock:  (87s)

so the locks are still there from before.  The locks stay there until I delete them or issue hg debuglocks -L -W.
For reference, issuing hg debuglocks in the local repo (on a local disk) gives

lock:  free
wlock: free

as it should.  This is the result I expect to get in the remote repo, but don't.
I suspect that there is some kind of atomic file or lock creation support in CIFS that has suddenly stopped working but I don't have the knowledge to debug any of this.  All other aspects of the CIFS-mounted drive behave completely normally.  I can manually create files and delete them with no problem.  It's just Mercurial that seems to be getting tripped up by its own locks.
Any ideas?

I think I found the answer.  Adding mfsymlinks to the mount options in /etc/fstab appears to have fixed the issue.  Apparently Mercurial does some kind of symlink magic while in the process of creating/manipulating the locks and cifs was choking on it.  I don't know why this functionality suddenly broke after years of working without a problem.
